# C# foreach list element in a list add a AddField

Tags: c#, foreach, embed, discord.net

I'm trying to create a discord bot which sends embed messages using the discord.net package.

This discord package brings a function to create embeds called EmbedBuilder which can be seen here: https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.EmbedBuilder.html

The following function works great. The code looks like this:

```
public async Task ExampleAsync()
{
    var embedElement = new EmbedBuilder()
        .WithTitle("Example Name")
        .AddField("Working", "Example")
        .Build();

    var chnl = BotClient.GetChannel(123) as IMessageChannel;
    await chnl.SendMessageAsync(embed: embedElement);
}
```

But let's say I have a List containing users and I wanted to add a `AddField("Working", "Example")` for each user in my list how would I do this?

Because things like the following are clearly not working and I can't find any info on this.

```
public List<UserObject> Users;

public async Task ExampleAsync()
{
    var embedElement = new EmbedBuilder()
        .WithTitle("Example Name")
        foreach(UserObject user in Users) 
        {
            .AddField("Working", "Example")
        }
        .Build();

    var chnl = BotClient.GetChannel(123) as IMessageChannel;
    await chnl.SendMessageAsync(embed: embedElement);
}
```

I would appreciate any kind of help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public List<UserObject> Users;

public async Task ExampleAsync()
{
    var embedElement = new EmbedBuilder().WithTitle("Example Name");
    foreach(UserObject user in Users) 
    {
        embedElement.AddField("Working", "Example");
    }
    embedElement.Build();

    var chnl = BotClient.GetChannel(123) as IMessageChannel;
    await chnl.SendMessageAsync(embed: embedElement);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks :) Just had to change embedElement.Build(); to var buildEmbed = embedElement.Build(); and assign buildEmbed in the SendMessageAsync.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `ForEach` method: `Users.ForEach(_ => embedElement.AddField("Working", "Example"));`